# How to print accents in verbatim?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, warnings, layout

I have this code:

```
\begin{verbatim}
  Serial.begin(9600);    // definisce velocit\`a porta seriale
  bt.begin(9600);    // inizializzera' comuinicazione Bluetooth
  display.setBrightness(0x0f);    // definisce inizializzera'à del display
\end{verbatim}
```

I want to print accents but it's showed like:

1. velocit\`a
2. inizializzera'
3. inizializzer ̃A ̈

How can I solve?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
Serial.begin(9600);    // definisce la velocità della porta seriale
bt.begin(9600);    // inizializzerà la comunicazione Bluetooth
display.setBrightness(0x0f);   // definisce àèéìòùÀÈÉÌÒÙ 
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Don't indent the code in `verbatim`.

If you don't get proper accented characters, it's very likely that your file is not UTF-8 encoded. Either convert all files to this encoding or load

```
\usepackage[<option>]{inputenc}
```

with the proper encoding option.

For quite a long time, various input encodings have been supported in LaTeX making unnecessary to resort to the classical input for accents (at least for the most common ones).